# How to catch the object_id of a post submit in Node.js (MongoJS)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code in app.js where I insert the content of the `title` and `content` fields to their respective document fields in MongoDB:

```
//post to 'post/new'..
app.post('/post/new', function(req, res){
//get the `title` and `content` fields & save them as variables to be later reused (they rely on the `name:` values).
var title = req.body.title;
var content = req.body.content;
//call the database and find the `_id` to be used in the redirect later..
db.local.find({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(id) {});
//insert the title and content in the database (taken from the submit form)
db.local.insert ( {title: title, content: content},
//not sure if I really need to define an err&doc right now so to be ignored..
function(err, doc) {
//redirect to "localhost.com/post/(post)_id/(post)title"
       res.redirect('/post/'+req.params.id+'/'+req.body.title);
  });
});
```

This is what I have on `post_new.ejs`:

```
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Title :</span>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="editPostTitle" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Content :</span>
      <textarea name="content" rows="20" id="editPostBody"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id='editPostSubmit'>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that I get all but no `_id` in the res.redirect to work, meaning, the title works wonderfully, but the _id no..

How can I get the object id to work in the redirect? Thank you!

**EDIT**
This is the problem I get and think it's unrelated..but I'll include it for the full view of the issue.

```
500 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [native node MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) the callback of the insert function returns the array of inserted objects.

The example in those docs is a pretty good one. Adjusted for your example, it would like something like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  db.collection('local').insert({title: title, content: content}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log('Inserted _id is '+docs[0]._id);    
  });
});
```

Regarding your error, it sounds like `req.params.id` is not a valid [BSON ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).